# Swisstopo-WMS not working in QField

Tags: qfield

When adding a layer from the swisstopo wms-server https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.3.0 (e.g. swissimage Hintergrund), it will not be shown in QField. There is an error which says that the layer can not be loaded, when starting QField.

Layers from the wmTs-server https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/EPSG/2056/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml don’t get the error, but are not shown in QField (which might be because of QField does not support wmTS-format?).

Other WMS servers work perfectly, e.g. OpenStreetMap from http://ows.mundialis.de/services/service

In QGIS all of them work perfectly

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It doesnt list [WMTS](https://docs.qfield.org/reference/data-format/) services. I have not tried any though

Comment: Exactly. That's what I wanted to point out with _"which might be because of QField does not support wmTs-format?"_ WMS should work tough - and worked in the past.

Comment: After uninstalling and installing the newest QField version (2.8.2), everything works fine again. Even layers from the wmTs-server are shown. I still don’t know why they weren’t shown anymore tough.